# codeigniter pagination via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-pagination

Is it possible to generate `CI pagination` via `ajax` sending `page numbers` through `ajax` instead of `$config['url_segment']`.

```
$(document).on("click",".pagination li a",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var segment = $(this).attr("data-ci-pagination-page");
    if(!segment){
        segment = 0;
    }
    $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/function",
            data: {limit: segment}
        }).done(function($data){
            $("#contents").html($data);
        });

});
```

if I pass pagination variables through `ajax` how can I `config` them.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem in the code that you have ?

Comment: (1)  I cant handle multiple pagination. (2) necessary to load data through `ajax` in case if pagination send data through `url segment` I cant Manage both `ajax` and `php` in same time

Comment: I guess you wan't to have navigation and pagination (All in ajax calls) Isn't it ?

Comment: I have to load  table of details. that `table details` should change according to `select > options` .. each time `pagination` also should be appear according to the `row count`.  so I create a `function` which `echo` all the `html` to the view  `pagination` also working but the `pagination` only shows three numbers (fixed).

Comment: Why not you do [Data Tables](https://www.datatables.net/) ?

Comment: Thanx.. anyway cant we handle `Codeigniter pagination` via `ajax`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81000/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-kanishka-b-kodithuwakku).